# Why 2nd PIR sensor is always HIGH?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I an getting a constant HIGH from 'inputPintwo' on the serial monitor.  When 'inputPin' goes HIGH the relay is triggered and works properly because 'inputPintwo' is also HIGH (all the time).

I have a Very similar setup to:  [2 PIR motion sensors +Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824873/2-pir-motion-sensors-arduino)

I am not using pin 0 or 1 like the above answered question.  I have replaced the sensor with a different one, in case it was bad hardware.  I also unplugged the sensor and it still reads HIGH.  The jumper is on retriggering on both sensors.

```
    int ledPin = 13;
    int inputPin = 2;
    int inputPintwo = 4;
    int pirState = LOW;
    int val = 0;
    int valtwo = 0;
    #define RELAY1  7

    void setup() {
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
      pinMode(inputPintwo, INPUT);
      pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop(){
      val = digitalRead(inputPin);
      valtwo = digitalRead(inputPintwo);

      if (val == HIGH && valtwo == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        if (pirState == LOW) {
          Serial.println("Motion detected!");
          pirState = HIGH;
          Serial.println("Light ON");
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,1);
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,0);
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,1);
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,0);
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,1);
          }
        }
      else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        if (pirState == HIGH){
          Serial.println("Motion ended!");
          digitalWrite(RELAY1,0);
          pirState = LOW;
          Serial.println("Light OFF");

        }
      }
    }
```

I expect both sensors to go HIGH only when motion is detected, which will cause the relay to go on and off several times, then stay on until the timer runs out on the sensors.

Comment: PIR sensors usually hold the HIGH state and send a LOW pulse if motion is detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the problem I recommend you to start with checking the hardware. You will need voltmeter/multimeter.

1. Double check if you are interfacing the sensor properly (check datasheet). Didn't you forget to connect e.g. the pull-down resistors?
2. Check power supply voltage on sensors – is the voltage within
   manufacturer specifications?
3. Check breadboard connections if you are using one.
4. Check sensor output behaviour (voltage), if there is or is not a movement. Is the voltage constant or not? Constant voltage means that PIR sensor is NOT working properly. Before performing of this test disconnect output from Arduino input.

If everything seems OK or you do not have voltmeter, try to disconnect the PIR sensor and connect a wire between Arduino pin 4 and ground. Does digitalRead(inputPintwo) return LOW? If yes, you know that reading of the pin state works fine.

---

Below please see some recommendations related to your code:

- use #define directive or static const int variable type to define Arduino pins as you do it with relay output pin RELAY1.

Example:

```
#define LED_PIN 13
#define INPUT_PIN 2
#define INPUT_PINTWO 4
```

or

```
static const int ledPin = 13;
static const int inputPin = 2;
static const int inputPintwo = 4;
```

- In your case, where you are only interested in digital value (LOW/HIGH), use built pull-up resistor on the input pins. Thus the log. voltage level on the floating input pin is defined (HIGH). If you do not use pull-up resistors, voltage can be either log. 0 (LOW) or log. 1 (HIGH), what can lead to strange program/state machine behaviour

To activate pull-up resistors in the input pins, use

```
pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(inputPintwo, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Comment: I am an amateur at electronics and I really appreciate the response but some of it is above my pay grade.  I am using these modules:  https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor  .  Most of my code was modified from this tutorial page as well.  I wonder if the pull-up resistor is built in to this board?  I will check what my voltages are with a voltmeter and report my findings.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I had all this equipment on my desk and I was using an 'AND' gate chip and everything was working.  I switched over to coding both sensors to turn the relay and then there was trouble.  Makes me think its more a code issue.

Comment: So I needed to swap out sensors.  I also changed the code using the '#define'.  I added some print lines to tell me what sensor was triggered and I got both of them to signal correctly.  Unfortunately for me forklifts will trigger both sensors when driving by because of their size and speed.  It will fulfill its purpose of warning people of the blind corner that it is installed on though.  Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Serial output feedback (print lines) is always a good practise since there is not so many other ways, how to debug Arduino code. Built-in LED is also handy for that purpose...

Comment: Also for your application ultrasonic sensors could be more suitable, but process signals from those sensors is not so easy...